# after string formatting method result changes

Tags: java, salesforce

I'm using [force-rest-api](https://github.com/jesperfj/force-rest-api) to do queries to salesforce and retrieve `json` answer and make java object.

```
public class SomeObject {
    @JsonProperty("field")
    private String field;
    @JsonProperty("list")
    private List<AnotherObject> list;
}
```

When I query string plainly - it returns correct result.

```
String requestQuery1 = "SELECT ... ='1111'";
return forceApi.query(requestQuery, clazz); // both field and list have data
```

But when add wildcard and use `string format` to create parametrized query - it returns incorrect result

```
String requestQuery = "SELECT  ... ='%s'";
requestQuery = String.format(query, (Object[]) queryParams); // array of parameters. usually new Object[] { 1111 }.
return forceApi.query(requestQuery, clazz); // field is not null, list is null
```

I tried to check strings using

```
assert requestQuery1.equals(requestQuery);
```

but they are the same. When I put `requestQuery` manually using debug and set its value

```
"SELECT ... ='1111'"
```

It works fine. 
But why it doesn't work when I use formatting? What's the problem?

Comment: `%s` acts a place holder for a string varialbe in `String.format()`, so it will replace that position with a string you're passing `queryParams`

Comment: It's a string parameter anyway

Comment: `%` is implicitly used by `String.format()`, that's how it usually start matching the patterns. `String.format("This is number - %s",1111);` this will print `This is number - 1111` replacing `%s` with the string returned by `Integer.valueOf(1111).toString()`